# Immutable JS - Creating an OrderedMap from a List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, redux, immutable.js

I have a `List`

```
const results = [94, 88, 121, 17];
```

and also a `Map`

```
const posts = {
   94: { title: 'Foo bar', content: 'Blah blah blah...' },
   88: { title: 'Bar Foo', content: 'Blah blah blah...' },
   121: { title: 'Bing bang', content: 'Blah blah blah...' },
   17: { title: 'Ning nang', content: 'Blah blah blah...' },
};
```

The `List` actually holds the order of the items in the `Map` as maps/objects can not guarantee order.

**Whats the most efficient way to create an `OrderedMap` using both the `List` and the `Map` above?**

Comment: `Immutable.OrderedMap(results.map(id => [id, posts.get(id.toString())]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in constructor in Immutable.js that will handle this, so you'll have to do the mapping yourself:

```
const orderedPosts = new OrderedMap(results.map(key => [key, posts[key]]))
```

Comment: Thanks thats what i though, but more importantly am i missing something here? Would a maps order be trustworthy? Is this super expensive computationally?

Comment: Yes, since `Array#map` is a method on `Array`, like all such methods, its results are in the order of the array you're operating on.  As for efficiency, you would have to do some profiling.  I would expect it to be efficient (no reason it shouldn't be O(n)).

Comment: No sorry I was meaning is the order of a `Map` trust worthy? But thank you! it seems efficient..

Comment: The order of `Map` (either the native ES2015 implementation or Immutable.js) is not guaranteed.  Hence `OrderedMap` in Immutable.js.

Comment: Ok last Question, is it possible to access a `List` as an array like you have? e.g. `myList[key]` or do i need to `myList.get(key)`

Comment: An Immutable.js `List`?  No...JavaScript does not support operator overloading (sadly), so you have to use `List#get` with an integer index.  It's analogous to an array, but you have to use `get` instead of square brackets.

Comment: Well there is a esNext proposal. overloading operators.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143099/discussion-between-ethan-brown-and-andrewmclagan).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map now remembers the insertion order. so you can use the Javascript Map.

```
// you can either create Map from existing object
const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(posts));

// or you can insert one by one, 
myMap.set(94,{ title: 'Foo bar', content: 'Blah blah blah...' })

// NOTE: key in map need not be string only

// map can be iterated using forEach
myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(`${key} = ${value}`);
});
```